# Remove unnecessary slashes from a given path with bash

Tags: bash, path

How can I get rid of unnecessary slashes in a given path?

Example:

```
p="/foo//////bar///hello/////world"
```

I want:

```
p="/foo/bar/hello/world"
```

Answer (score 31):

Use [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink):

```
p=$(readlink -m "/foo//////bar///hello/////world")
```

Notice that this will canonicalize symbolic links. If that's not what you want, use [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
p=$(echo "/foo//////bar///hello/////world" | sed s#//*#/#g)
```

Comment: Could use `readlink -m` instead, and the directory doesn't need to exist.

Comment: @Ryan Li Thanks, that's indeed way better. Updated.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried `sed 's/\/\//\//g'` which doesnt worked in the way I want.

Answer (score 15):

your input:

```
p="/foo//////bar///hello/////world"
```

command to remove the irrelevant slashes:

```
echo $p | tr -s /
```

output:

```
/foo/bar/hello/world
```

Comment: this is definitely my favorite solution to the problem. Just for reference here are 2 additional ones using sed: `echo $p | sed -r 's|/+|/|g'` or `echo $p | sed 's|//*|/|g'`

Comment: Very cool option of `tr -s / --squeeze-repeats` to squeeze all repeated character into one. Thanks the shortest solution!

Answer (score 11):

Using pure Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo ${p//+(\/)/\/}
```

Comment: would not `+(\/)` be the same as `\/*(\/)` ?

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, I'll update my answer. I have no idea why I didn't use that in the first place all those years ago. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9):

With realpath:

`realpath -sm $p`

Parameters:

```
  -m, --canonicalize-missing   no components of the path need exist
  -s, --strip, --no-symlinks   don't expand symlinks
```

Comment: I needed to keep paths relative, even if they wouldn't have a leading slash. So I did `realpath -sm "/$p"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider if you need to do this. On Unix, specifying duplicate path separators (and even things like `/foo/.//bar///hello/./world` work just fine.
2. You can use `readlink -f`, but this will also canonicalize the symlinks in that path, so the result depends on your filesystem and the path supplied must actually exist, so this won't work for virtual paths.

Comment: most of the time, extra slashes work fine, but in some cases they cause problems (I once had this with an rsync option not working correctly if the path had doubles slashes)

Answer (score 0):

This works with multiple separators and does not assume the given path should exist:

```
p=/foo///.//bar///foo1/bar1//foo2/./bar2; 
echo $p | awk '{while(index($1,"/./")) gsub("/./","/"); while(index($1,"//"))
     gsub("//","/");  print $1;}'
```

But does not simplify well strings containing ".."

Answer (score 0):

In zsh:

```
echo "${p:a}"
```

Works with non-existent paths, too.

Comment: This worked great for me.  Not sure why you were down voted

Answer (score -5):

Thanks for the replys. I know the path works fine. I just want this for optical reasons.

I found another solution: `echo $p | replace '//' ''`

Comment: Wrong: `a//b////c` will give `abc`.