# How to split path by last slash?

Tags: bash, split

I have a file (say called `list.txt`) that contains relative paths to files, one path per line, i.e. something like this:

```
foo/bar/file1
foo/bar/baz/file2
goo/file3
```

I need to write a bash script that processes one path at a time, splits it at the last slash and then launches another process feeding it the two pieces of the path as arguments. So far I have only the looping part:

```
for p in `cat list.txt`
do
   # split $p like "foo/bar/file1" into "foo/bar/" as part1 and "file1" as part2
   inner_process.sh $part1 $part2
done
```

How do I split? Will this work in the degenerate case where the path has no slashes?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use `basename` and `dirname`, that's all you need.

```
part1=$(dirname "$p")
part2=$(basename "$p")
```

Comment: An issue with this is how do you combine the parts to get back the full path? `$part1/$part2` mostly works, except if `$p` is `/etc` you will get `//etc`.

Comment: @DanielDarabos `//etc` is a valid synonym for `/etc` in most contexts. However, see this question for solutions if you need to remove double slashes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4638983/3776640

Answer (score 19):

A proper 100% bash way and which is safe regarding filenames that have spaces or funny symbols (provided `inner_process.sh` handles them correctly, but that's another story):

```
while read -r p; do
    [[ "$p" == */* ]] || p="./$p"
    inner_process.sh "${p%/*}" "${p##*/}"
done < list.txt
```

and it doesn't fork `dirname` and `basename` (in subshells) for each file.

The line `[[ "$p" == */* ]] || p="./$p"` is here just in case `$p` doesn't contain any slash, then it prepends `./` to it.

See the [*Shell Parameter Expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for more info on the `%` and `##` symbols.

Answer (score 18):

I found a great solution from this [source](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/34310-splitting-up-absolute-filepath.html).

```
p=/foo/bar/file1
path=$( echo ${p%/*} )
file=$( echo ${p##*/} )
```

This also works with spaces in the path!

Comment: rather `${p##*/}`

Comment: The subshell + echo is also completely unnecessary, and the current solution runs into the usual word splitting issues due to unquoted expansions. Don’t write this. Just use `path=${p%/*}` and `file=${p##*/}`. Or use `basename` and `dirname`.

Answer (score 1):

While basename and dirnames are really helpful, maybe you are in the same situation as me:

I need to get only the first Nth folders of a path, and I can be on any folder, like these ones: `/home/me/folder/i/want/`, `/home/me/`, or `/home/me/folder/i/want/folder/i/dont/want/`.

So I used [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).

Here's the command to get only `/home/me/folder/i/want`, no matter where I am:

```bash
echo "/home/me/folder/i/want/folder/i/dont/want" | cut -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 -d "/"
```

Here, cut is splitting the string by "/" chars, and is displaying 1st, 2nd [...] 6th words only.

Here are some examples:

```bash
$ echo $PWD
/home/me/folder/i/want/folder/i/dont/want
$ echo $PWD | cut -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 -d "/"
/home/me/folder/i/want
$ cd ../../../..
$ echo $PWD
/home/me/folder/i/want
$ echo $PWD | cut -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 -d "/" 
/home/me/folder/i/want
$ cd ~
echo $PWD | cut -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 -d "/"       
/home/me
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is one example to find and replace file extensions to xml.

```
for files in $(ls); do

    filelist=$(echo $files |cut -f 1 -d ".");
    mv $files $filelist.xml;
done
```