# Removing an additional leading slash if one exists

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script where I have a default directory for outputting data or the user can specify a directory.  The problem is, I don't know how to do this eloquently.  Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT="$1"

DEFAULT_DIR=/Default/Dir/For/Me

if [ -z "$OUTPUT" ] 
then
   OUTPUT=.${DEFAULT_DIR}
else
   OUTPUT=""${OUTPUT_DIR}""${DEFAULT_DIR}""
fi

echo "$OUTPUT"
```

- If I do this `./script /` I get `//Default/Dir/For/Me`
- If I do this `./script /home` I get `/home/Default/Dir/For/Me`
- If I do this `./script /home/` I get `/home//Default/Dir/For/Me`

Is there any way to make this pretty and handle the first scenario properly?  Obviously, the first scenario won't work because the directory `//` does not exist.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638983/remove-unnecessary-slashes-from-a-given-path-with-bash

Comment: What about piping it with `tr -s "/"`? It will remove duplicate slashes.

Comment: @fedorqui this works!  So simple, so elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Just to make it clear from the comments)

What I suggest is to pipe `tr -s "/"` so that it removes duplicate slashes:

```
$ echo "/home//Default/Dir/For/Me" | tr -s "/"
/home/Default/Dir/For/Me
$ echo "/home//Default/Dir/For/M//////////e" | tr -s "/"
/home/Default/Dir/For/M/e
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution without having to fork another process:

```
DEFAULT_DIR=${DEFAULT_DIR//\/\///}
```

That replaces all occurrences of `//` with `/` in the string.

Comment: That's `bash` syntax for substituting patterns in variables - `${VARIABLE/old/new}` replaces the first occurrence of `old` with `new` in the expansion of the variable; `${VARIABLE//old/new}` replaces all occurrences. The above looks odd because of the need to escape the slashes in the `old` portion of the replacement.